# Control the height and the length of a frame

Tags: floats, framed

By using the following code, I draw a framed figure that contains an array of 3 rows:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{framed}
  \[
  \begin{array}{l}
    a \\
    b \\
    c
  \end{array}
  \]
  \end{framed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to reduce the space between `a` and the frame above? How to reduce the space between `c` and the frame below?

Additionally, what if I want to reduce the length of the frame (now, it is almost same as the length of the texts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate the spacing set `\FrameSep` and the display math spacing:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}%
  \begin{framed}%
      \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \[
  \begin{array}{l}
    a \\
    b \\
    c
  \end{array}
  \]
  \end{framed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```